# How to remove ACLs on Remote Disk

Tags: powershell, acl, ntfs

I'm trying to find a way to remove 'CREATOR OWNER' and Everyone from the security of a disk. I tried make it work with `Get-Acl` and `Set-Acl`. Then I tried the module `NTFSSecurity`, but that only seemed to work on folders.

```
Import-Module NTFSSecurity

Get-Item "L:\" | Remove-NTFSAccess -Account 'Everyone' -AccessRights ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
Get-Item "L:\" | Remove-NTFSAccess -Account 'Everyone' -AccessRights ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
Get-Item "L:\" | Remove-NTFSAccess -Account 'CREATOR OWNER' -AccessRights GenericAll
Get-Item "L:\" | Remove-NTFSAccess -Account 'CREATOR OWNER' -AccessRights GenericAll
```

The permissions are the default ones on a fresh installation.

[image]

Seems I can only make it work on folders.

Answer (score 2):

`Set-Acl` has some issues with handling SACLs and owners. You may want to use [`icacls`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx) instead:

```
icacls L:\ /remove 'creator owner' everyone
```